# checkbox - replace check mark with fa-link

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox set up. I am trying to get it to show a Font Awesome icon. Namely, `fa-link` when checked and nothing when not checked.

Here is the code:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
    appearance: initial;
    outline: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background: #0073C0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
    content: "\2713";
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    outline: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
}
```

```html
    <input id="box1" type="checkbox" />
```

It should look like this:

[image]

I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: if you are trying to render a Font Awesome icon you need to set the `font-family: 'FontAwesome';` where you set the `content` to the unicode character in the `:after` style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Font Awesome icons like this you will need to set the font family to FontAwesome where you set the unicode character for the content. Also, make sure you are using the correct unicode character (for the link icon its `\f0c1`)

Like this:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f0c1";
    ....
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0g7u8kz/) for a demo.

Comment: Theres a white dotted box around the fa-link. How can i remove this? Thanks

Comment: That is because you have the style `outline: 1px solid #A9A9A9;`, just remove it